# Django можно ли редиректить в файле urls.py?

Tags: python, django, redirect

Подскажите, могу ли я делать редирект в `urls.py` с определенной ссылки на другую страницу без запроса в `views.py`

Пример, файл `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('reg/', views.register, name='registration'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('', Вот здесь редирект на страницу 'login' )
]
```

Comment: все можно, вся жизнь у ваших руках

Comment: Можно, для этого есть RedirectView https://djbook.ru/rel3.0/ref/class-based-views/base.html#redirectview

Comment: @entithat Юхууу